# Identifying duplicates using multiple criteria and is not blank or does not equal

Tags: excel

I'm needing to use formulas in a table to identify duplicates using multiple criteria.

First I'm reviewing all delivery numbers to indicate multiples, however I'm only interested in counting when, additionally, the invoice amount is not blank.

I seem to be unable to formulate with the <> or NOT(ISBLANK()) within my COUNTIFS statement.

**Current Formula**

[image: Current Formula]

Thanks!

I've tried quotes around <> and different variations of NOT(ISBLANK())

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I THINK this is what you're looking for:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS([Delivery '#],[@[Delivery '#]],[Amount],"<>")>1,"DUPLICATE","")
```